# Plantuml. How to create finite state machine diagrams?

Tags: plantuml, state-diagram

I want to create a FSM diagram and wanted to use plantuml for that. I stuck with backward arrows
There is a way to create backward arrows but it looks overcomplicated and too limited for such a simple task

```
@startuml
:start;
repeat :Ask to enter login;
repeat while(Is name valid?) is (No) not (Yes)
:play game;
@enduml
```

which gives this
[image]

but when you want to implement a little bit more complex logic like:

1. Ask to enter name
2. Ask to enter password
3. On the third failed attempt go back to the (1)

it looks like it's just not possible with plantuml

I don't know if it called State diagram but I took a look on all types of diagrams plantuml supports and it seems to be the fittest one

Answer (score 1):

I would say that an [activity diagram](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta) works best.

What you described is easy to explain, but complex to display in correct UML, I don't think that's specific to plantuml. Here's how I would express what you said:

[image: PlantUML Activity Diagram]

```
@startuml
start
while (App) is (running)
  :enter username;
  repeat
    :enter password;
    if (Password correct?) then (yes)
      :Play game;
      stop
    endif
  repeat while (Third attempt?) is (no) not (yes)
endwhile (exit)
stop
@enduml
```

Comment: Can you make a additional sub-branch `play game -> AFK too long -> enter password`?

Answer (score 1):

As [Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68456452/3723423) pointed out, you are more likely thinking in terms of activity diagram, your nodes being the actions that happen and not the states.

If you want a state diagram, you need to shift your mind to the background of your currently identified actions.  So in the simplest means, there are two main states in your system:

[image]

Let's zoom into the first state, which appears to be more complex and deserve some substates. You have identified an  `Enter a name` action while in the game configuration state.  Until this action is completed, the name is not known. Once it is completed, the name will be known, but a validity check needs to be performed.   You could express this with the following states:

[image]

You'll see that when entering the substate No valid name known,  the first things that happens is to ask the name.  And once everything is fine,  you've finished the sub-state machine and can continue to the new states.

The plantuml code is:

```
@startuml
state Configuring {
  state NameNotKnown as "No valid name known":entry / Ask name
  state NameKnown as "Name knwon"
  [*] --> NameNotKnown
  NameNotKnown --> NameKnown : Name entered
  NameKnown --> [*] : Name is valid
  NameKnown --> NameNotKnown: Name is invalid 
}
[*] --> Configuring 
Configuring --> Playing : Launch game
Playing --> [*] : Game over
@enduml
```

It's worth to mention that you could fine tune this diagram, using `entry`, `exit` and `do` behaviors in each [simple state](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#simple-state). Moreover, you could simplify my example using [guarded transitions](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#behavioral-transition), and even behaviours that are expressed at transition level.